# Zip Folder without file included

Tags: terminal, zip

How would I zip the contents of a folder without including some file

So I know that

```
zip -r ARCHIVE_NAME.zip ./FOLDER_NAME -x "**/node_modules/*" "*.git*"
```

would zip the folder without the **node_modules** folder and the **.git** folder, but when it comes to a single file ( not folder ) `"**/ap.zip*"` does not work

Comment: I think that -x should be used for each parameter given. At least this is what happen when "--exclude" is used

Comment: you are right - thank you!

Comment: I'll formalize this into an answer, since this can be useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every file or folder to be excluded the "-x" parameter.
You can try this:

```
zip -r ARCHIVE_NAME.zip ./FOLDER_NAME -x "**/node_modules/*" -x "*.git*"
```

or this

```
zip -r ARCHIVE_NAME.zip ./FOLDER_NAME --exclude "**/node_modules/*" --exclude"*.git*"
```